# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Blog_username

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-models

**django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Blog_username**

i got this error,I have designed my model already and I wanted to add a new table to the model called ***username*** in my models.py using SQLite in my Django application called **Blog**. And after adding it to my model I then use the following command to add it to my database:
Here is my Blog.models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Person(models.Model):
    username = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Here is my settings.py

```
..... 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    'Blog.apps.BlogConfig', 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

....
```

`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`

And I didn't get any error while running this command.
But later when i wanted to query the data in my database using the following command:
`python manage.py shell`
`from Blog.models import Person`
Note: Person is the name of the class in my database
`Person.objects.all()`
After running the last command I then got an error saying **django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Blog_username**. I had already run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands when I got that error.

Please I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this error and it really bothering me

Here is the Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Blog_username

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in __repr__
    data = list(self[: REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 398, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 91, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1562, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\django_project> python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'Blog':
  Blog\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Person
PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\django_project> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: Blog, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
PS C:\Users\dell\Desktop\django_project> python manage.py shell
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:34:50) [MSC v.1934 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from Blog.models import Person
>>> Person.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Blog_username

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 374, in __repr__
    data = list(self[: REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 398, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 91, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1562, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\python\Python311-32\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Blog_username
```

Comment: post your Blog.models

Comment: So sorry I didn't add it, I just did now.

Comment: Have added my model.py and my settings py @NickLangat

Comment: Did you at any point add a table called username? Looks like you are referencing it somewhere. Share your views as well.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the **whole** error message, instead of just the final line.

Comment: Also, the posted content of `models.py` only contains a `Person` model.  Where, exactly, did you add the new `username` table?

Comment: None of this code refers to "username" at all.  Are you sure this is your real code?

Comment: Ohh I made an error when copy pasting my code to stackoverflow. So I mistakenly forgot to add the username table when copying it am sorry @JohnGordon I will edit it now and also past the error it saying.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have I have added the missing table which I made mistake when copy pasting my code to stackoverflow. And I also added the Traceback error. I would appreciate it if you could assist with this . Cause am really have a hard time here

Comment: `username` is not a new **table** at all.  It is a new **field** in the `Person` model.  I don't see any code here that would try to access `username` as a separate table.  Are you **sure** you posted the full correct `models.py` file?